# In operating systems how the OS prevent infinite loops

Tags: operating-system, kernel

In operating system there should be a mechanism to prevent infinite loops. I want to know which steps follow the OS to prevent infinite loops and terminate the process by OS.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with an (over-simplified) example of an infinite loop:

```
 while(true) {
      get_user_input();
      handle_user_input();
 }
```

Almost every application you've ever used is (a more complex) infinite loop like this; and it's not just applications (e.g. a web server might loop forever while checking for new connections on a TCP/IP port).

Infinite loops are often necessary, and processes shouldn't be terminated just because they do something that may be necessary.

With this in mind the question becomes: How does an OS detect the difference between an unwanted and unintended infinite loop, and a wanted, intentional and necessary infinite loop?

The answer is that an OS can't.

What an OS can do is have various rules that have nothing to do with infinite loops; like:

- a high priority thread may only use 100 milliseconds of CPU time between calling a potentially blocking IO operation (e.g. like reading from a network socket); so that if a high priority thread consumes too much CPU time it can be declared "unresponsive" (regardless of whether it's in an infinite loop or not).
- a thread that communicates with the GUI must accept new events (user input, notifications, etc) within 1 second; so that if a thread takes too long to accept an event from GUI it can be declared "unresponsive" (regardless of whether it's in an infinite loop or not).

Of course this kind of thing is OS specific; and there aren't too many rules like this that won't cause problems for correct software.