# Does First Come First Serve (FCFS) suffer from Starvation?

Tags: operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

### Does First Come First Serve (FCFS)suffer from Starvation?

An esteemed computer science examination in India included this question.

The complete question goes as follows-

```
Which one or more of the following scheduling algorithms can potentially cause starvation?

A. First-in First-Out

B. Round Robin

C. Priority Scheduling

D. Shortest Job First
```

---

I have doubts about option A only, the rest of other options are fine.

- Let me first quote Berkeley university which says - "The FCFS algorithm will result in starvation only if some thread runs forever"

  Problem 5b, Page 15 -
  [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs162-F08/exams/fa07mt1-solutions.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ekubitron/courses/cs162-F08/exams/fa07mt1-solutions.pdf)
- And, William Stalling's book says - NO.

  William Stalling's book Screenshot -
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1JAm.png

---

In Galvin, I found an interesting point that says that we can not allow users to run an infinite loop so we implement a timer to prevent infinite loops.

Galvin's book Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiqK.png

(Obviously, it is undecidable problem to check if the program runs infinitely. A nice answer by SO user Brendan (34.7k points) about the same - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181828)

---

My question here is what should be the answer to the given OBJECTIVE question above?
and how to justify the answer given by William Stalling?

William Stalling's book has said that FCFS does not suffer from starvation but it does not mention any assumption.

If we have to claim that FCFS does not suffer from starvation then we have to first assume one of the following -

1. Users can not submit Infinite time jobs OR
2. The underlying OS has a timer to prevent infinite loops (in case the user submits such jobs)

Please help me to identify how William Stalling's book claim is true without mentioning the above assumptions.

Comment: FIFO, priority scheduling, and shortest-job-first are susceptible to starvation. In particular, FIFO is susceptible because it is defined as *non-preemptive* (so a thread that runs forever will starve the other threads), while the other two could prioritize other threads causing one or more threads to starve (regardless of whether the policies are preemptive). I would say the Stalling book seems to be incorrect when it says that FIFO is not susceptible to starvation.

Comment: IMO because the question says **potentially cause starvation?**. If a process contains indefinite loop obviously that will be definitely caused starvation for all non-preemptive algorithms, not just FIFO. Also if we consider all potentials, all algorithms mentioned can produce starvation. Even if for Round Robin, in a case of deadlock on resources other than CPU, the processes involved will never finish. So here the general assumption should be no indefinite loop. For me, for general cases (only involve CPU), C and D should be the answers.